# How and where to store dynamic result/data using webdriver java

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java, junit, testng

I want to know "How and where to store dynamic (Search results) result/data", I am getting the results and not sure what to do next.

Also, after saving these results I want to use this in another class (By index I want to compare with other values or .equals).

**Application url is:** `http://www.jabong.com/shoes/Puma/?qc=puma%20shoes&r=2`

**Below is the sample code, please let me know how to do it.**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test1 {
public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
static String[] imageLocation = null;

public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
driver.get("http://www.jabong.com/shoes/Puma/?qc=puma%20shoes&r=2");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/section/section/div[5]/div[2]"));
for(WebElement listOfOption :listOfOptions ){
System.out.println(listOfOption.getText());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello since you are getting the results in the List, you can export them to a file for use in future, or can use them further for comparison or whatever you need since the data is already stored in the List variable.

You can see in this sample code here - http://milinpatel17.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/web-page-link-test-using-selenium-webdriver/ that I have stored all the links in a webpage in a List variable and then run the list in a loop to check the http status of each link from the List.

Similarly I'll will look for an example of writing the list to a file and update it here! :)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Could you tell me how please (Sample code/Logic, etc), because spent lot of time on this but didn't get success.

Comment: Hello check the update in the answer above! Hope it will help you

Comment: It's worked.. :)

Comment: Great i'm glad i could help! :)

Comment: How to access these values in another class? (I want to compare these values in another class variable values).

Comment: I'm not really sure about as i too am still a beginner, but i think you should try and check the global variables and inheritance concepts of java. I guess that might help you with accessing variables over different classes!

Answer (score 1):

I found this really simple code to write output to file. You can find it here - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

You can customize the code to fit your need and write the list values to file by placing the bw.write() part withing a loop.

Comment: This is very useful :).. Voted up for this.

Comment: Always glad to help fellow testers! And ya, do write about the accessing of values in another classes. I'd really like to learn about it!

Comment: I am working on it, but not getting the particular solution.